# how to determine if user is logged in "recently" in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I'm trying to implement an angular guard to check if the user was signed in recently so they can change password, update email etc.

Using either angular fire 2 or angular I have a handle to the user (firebase.User). But how do I check if they qualify for "recently logged in" to perform sensitive operations?

```
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {


  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {

  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authService.user$.map((user) => {
      if (user) {
        // how to validate that this user is a recent login?
        return true;
      } else {
        console.log('not authenticated');
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
        return false;
      }
    }).first();
  }

  canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.canActivate(route, state);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just always re-authenticate before any sensitive information. It is common practice and Firebase provides APIs for re-authentication. You can check the `auth_time` in the Firebase ID token for the time of the last sign-in but Firebase Auth doesn't document the criteria for the recently logged in requirement and likely won't as they reserve the right to change it for security reasons. You are better off just requiring reauthentication, or you can try to updatePassword/updateEmail but if you get that specific error, reauthenticate and then try again.

Comment: where is `auth_time`? I tried `getIdToken` but it just resolves the token string.

Comment: I'm also confused how you implement the flow for reauthentication? I can't find a working example. I get it if you need to pass a password in the form to change password/name etc, but how does it work with a federated login like Gmail? How to get the credential object required by the method?

Comment: You have to parse that token string. You can use some JWT parsing library to do so. With federated sign-in, you can use `currentUser.reauthenticateWithPopup(provider)` or `currentUser.reauthenticateWithRedirect(provider)`. If you already have the Google access token or ID token, you can use `currentUser.reauthenticateWithCredential(firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(googleIdToken, googleAccessToken))`